# Bluetooth keeps turning on by itself - Is there a way to determine why?

Tags: settings, bluetooth, troubleshooting

I saw similar questions but there was no generic answer to the issue.
Is there a way to determine what is turning my BT ON? I don't have rooted phone (but can ADB)

I got Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android 6.0.1.

What I did:

1. Turned off BT scanning for "fine localization"
2. Revoked permission to change phone settings to ALL apps that had one (including g services)
3. Disabled all BT scanning related things that I have found.

How to find what is turning BT on?

Comment: As you mention you "can ADB", my first look would be into `adb logcat`. Redirect that into a file, then search there for "bluetooth" (case insensitive).

Comment: Add to @Izzy comment: also search for "bt" (case insensitive) string.

Answer (score 0):

You gave permission to all apps to change the phone settings as per need which means some app which uses Bluetooth connection is using that to turn the Bluetooth on. Change that setting and it will work fine

Comment: I have revoke all apps that were listed - still bt turns on

Comment: Then it might be phones software malfunction and nothing can be done

Comment: @Sanjay its " *you cant do anything ". Antoniossss have you tried restarting the phone because it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Get a rom from ubuntu touch for a similar device and try installing it. If it works, inform the team that ubuntu touch works for that particular device. It looks like your OS is compromised which is an increasing feature of the soon to be deprecated android operation system. Fushia will be the next google mobile OS and it will ship without GPL2 end user protections. Now more than ever we need proper GNU/Linux phones to take off.